# What does draft mean in app status in dashboard?

Tags: flutter

I published an app in playstore 2 days back using flutter, and in the dashboard there is draft in app status, and 'In review' in update status. Is there any extra work I need to do?? Can anybody help??

Answer (score 0):

When the app is in review, it means that Google Play team is reviewing your app and it will be published once it's approved (unless you chose not to publish it immediately), so there is noting you can do to the app at that time

Dart app means that you've created an app, filled none or some of it's information (Store listing, apk or aab, ...) and did not do anything after that, so it's not ready to publish, it's just an empty app "profile" and you can delete this app if you've made it by mistake or if you don't want it anymore, this will not effect you other app.

Comment: ohh, I am also bothered by the 'draft' in the 'app status' tab. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: if you've submitted the app for review once, then the draft app cannot be deleted, 
if it's deletable, you can find the trash icon next to the "pin" icon
I know it's bothering, I have an app like that, but sadly, you can't do anything about it if it's not deletable :(
also it won't effect your other apps